# Scrollable Wicket datatable with headers fixed

Tags: wicket-1.6

I want to create a Datatable with headers fixed and body scrollable. I tried with out Headers Tool Bar and created Headers manually in HTML page. But table content and Headers are not getting aligned properly. If lengthy column is there, table content is moving left and headers are fixed there.

Answer (score 0):

Without much information I would say this is not a wicket issue and instead a CSS problem.  You should look into using CSS to style the table and header

Comment: ,I did that. But my headers and table columns are not getting aligned properly. is there any way to fix the length of each data table column. so that i'll keep the same length in CSS for headers.